# Should I put every kind of configuration in package.json file in front-end development?

Tags: configuration-management

Currently we need manage lots of development tools' configuration, like ESLint and Jest. One way is to store their configuration in `package.json`. Another way is store this configuration in their special config file, like `jest.config.js`.

Which way do you prefer? How you do these in your project? I think the separate way is better because it separates the concerns.

Comment: Putting many disparate configurations inside package.json will cause your coworkers' heads to explode. Please don't do that. I would always expect each tool to have its own configuration file for separation of concerns.

Comment: I don't understand why this question should be down vote? I saw lots of configurations keeped in `package.json` file, so I am confused

Answer (score 0):

## Concerns

What is the concern of the package.json?

No seriously, what is its point?

As far as I'm aware its purpose is to be a manifest that describes this module, and its dependencies for the compilation/linting/packaging tools used by the developer, but also for those reliant on this package.

Last time I checked, those who depend on this package couldn't care less what your specific linter settings are. If they want to lint your files, they will use their rules.

## Change Management

Your specific organisation may have a lenient change management practices, but imagine explaining why this file change late in a project, say two days prior to release just before a big event that must be pulled off successfully.

Let's have the conversation around `eslint`: Ah yes that is a development file, that is not packaged and released. It's a nothing change.

Now about package.json: Ah yes that is the manifest that governs dependency management in the project. Oh but that is just a dev only section. Well yes it's copied into the package. But it does nothing. No it wasn't tested. No it's not going to break. No we didn't perform an integration test, we were just doing a dev orientated change. Okay, I'll back it out.

## Appendices

It's hard enough to delete code when it's in its own file. You have to prove that nothing relies on it. The positive is that as a file, it is easy to see as a discrete unit.

Trying to delete a section from a file is even harder. You have to prove that no one uses that section, even if they load it. If the file is crucial to have working it will often be left behind because the effort to prove nothing breaks is too high.

Comment: Not that I disagree but note that the package.json in the project root isn't always the one that gets included in the package (build tooling might generate a new one, for example). Also there's a lot of space between "leninent change management" and "someone who doesn't know enough to really understand the answers is going to ask why each file changed", and with half-decent practices you can answer "of course it was tested, every commit goes through the pipeline" anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe such an idyllic world. How familiar are you with government regulators? While I agree that such an outcome would be ideal, not every company has or can have such a luxury, simply because of none programmers who do not understand the risk.